How do I bring the MedicineDetails card below nameRow (Box) using constraint layout?
This is how my preview looks without the MedicineDetails card
I want MedicineDetails card to be aligned below Add Medicine Box. I used constraint layout to do this.
But MedicineDetails card is coming on top of the Add Medicine Box. 
@Composable
fun AddMedicine() {
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            val (nameRow, list, card, topBar) = createRefs()
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_topbar), contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(topBar) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                })

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 64.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
                .constrainAs(nameRow) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }) {
                Text(
                    text = "Add Medicine",
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                )
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_back),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)
                )
            }

            MedicineDetails(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(card) {
                        top.linkTo(nameRow.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}

I have linked the top of MedicineDetails to bottom of nameRow but why isn't it working?

This is not Java...

@UsagiMiyamoto Please consider directly editing such a post in the future, as you have enough reputation to do so. I know edited it and removed the java tag.

@Arya Your code looks fine to me. Please edit your post and also include the MedicineDetails Composable. There might be something pushing the Card up, like a fillMaxHeight() or similar.
